# Unable to find a specification for `Firebase`

Tags: ios, firebase, installation, cocoapods

I'm unable to install Firbase pod, when trying:

```
pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `Firebase`
```

Here is my podfile :

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'login' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for login

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe your pod isn't synced? Try:

```
pod repo update --verbose
```

Comment: pod repo update --verbose  --> stuck after this

    Updating spec repo `master`
    $ /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only

Comment: Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `HarpAppDelegatey`

doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was with my local pod repo. I fixed by doing the following:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try
pod 'Firebase/Core'
Instead of just pod 'Firebase'.
I had the same problem and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try below commands:

`pod repo remove master
pod repo update
pod install --verbose`