# Xcode - Unable to find a specification for `Firebase`

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods, specifications

When i am trying to `pod install` with my `podfile`, in Xcode 7.3.1 project.
I getting error message (Terminal)

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for 'Firebase'
```

My pod file is:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'UserLogin' do

    pod ‘Firebase’
    pod ‘Firebase/Auth’

end
```

and when i try `pod install --verbose`

```
Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-UserLogin`: (``)

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
[!] Unable to find a specification for `Firebase`

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:442:in `handle_resolver_error'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:65:in `rescue in resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:57:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:563:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:63:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:561:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:76:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:227:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:151:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:63:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:150:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:114:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:37:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

I have tried many ways but 'pod install' still does not work. I do not have two files `Podfile.lock` and `.xcworkspace`.

Anyone has a similar problem?

Comment: try to replace quotes `‘` and `’` with `'`. Try run `pod repo update` also

Comment: In my case the problem was with the pod repo. I fixed by doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40428894/2091181